# cross-domain returns not unicoded characters

Tags: javascript, unicode, cross-domain

I am using whateverorigin.org to make a cross-domain call and get the html back to show in a div. But some not english chracters are strange (a little square). following is my code.

```
$.ajaxSetup({ scriptCharset: "utf-8" , contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"});

$.getJSON('http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent('https://www.testserver/index.html') + '&callback=?', function(data){
            $("div#test").html(data.contents);
        });
```

How do I get back right characters.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a JSONP request, which is implemented by adding a `<script>` element to the current page pointing at the remote content, instead of using normal XMLHttpRequest.

Whereas XHR/JSON responses are decoded with UTF-8, `<script>`s are interpreted using whatever the browser thinks the current page's encoding is. So if you've not specified that, by using `<meta charset="UTF-8">` or `Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8`, then the browser will have to guess. If it guesses something other than UTF-8 (which is very likely) then the included script will be misdecoded.

Comment: thanks, but my first line of the code should solve the problem. doesn't it?¨

Comment: I change my first line of the code to text/html;charset=utf-8 but the non english characters are square.

Comment: `scriptCharset` doesn't work on all browsers, unfortunately, so you have to make sure to set the charset of the page to match as well. Next thing to check is that the page you are fetching from `https://www.testserver/index.html` itself has a `<meta charset>` or `Content-Type` header, because without that WhateverOrigin itself has to guess what encoding that page is in, and may guess wrongly.

Comment: It is not the problem because when I use IFrame to show the html file (from other domain) the characters are normal. and the other part of the page which contains non english characters are normal. so it is something with whateverorigin.org (api) which changes the characters.

Comment: Putting it in an iframe is not a representative test. That will allow the browser to have a guess at the charset if one isn't specified, which may result in a different guess to WhateverOrigin's guess.